# In Windows 10/11 is there a way to script a device to use a specific driver, even if its not marked as compatible?

Tags: windows, powershell, driver

I was hoping to see if anyone has had any luck scripting the assignment of a specific driver to a device?

I've tried using `pnputil` to install the driver, it gets added to the store but the device does not automatically pick it up.

If I do this manually in Device Manager using the have disk option, it works fine.

The only thing I can see that might be causing an issue is during the manual method I have to untick "Show compatible devices" to select the driver.

We understand the risk of not using a "compatible" driver, so hoping it might be a case of using a flag to "force" the device to use it in the scripted method?

Any advice on how to achieve this would be most appreciated.

I've managed to install the driver to the driver store but have not been able to assign it to the device. Device Manager seems to be able to do this, though.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon